# How to make a custom vlookup in vba?

Tags: excel, vba

Hi I am learning vba these days. I was trying to make a user defined Vlookup function. Now I know that there is a default vlookup function that can be used but just to get things cleared I thought of making one. So here is my code but it gives me a value error. I had tried debugging but the debugging somehow stops after the if statement.

```
Option Explicit
Function vlookup_a(x As Range, y As Range, z As Integer) As Variant
    Dim nr As Integer, i As Integer
    nr = y.Rows.Count

    i = 1
    Do While vlookup_a <> y(i, z)
        If y(i, 0) = x.Value Then
            vlookup_a = y(i, z)
            Exit Function
        Else
            i = i + 1
        End If

    Loop
End Function
```

Comment: there is no column `0`: `y(i, 1)`

Comment: Note: `nr` assignment will blow up with an *Overflow* error if `y.Rows` is greater than 32,767. Use `Long`, not `Integer`.

Comment: Also, I suggest renaming the variables. `x`, `y`, and `z` don't mean anything and make it a little tricky to follow the UDF.

Comment: Thanks a ton  Matthieu Guindon and Bruce Wayne. Actually I come from python background so didn’t realise that there is no 0th column. And yeah would change the data type.